# How to call one cell of a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to using PHP so I am asking for some help. I have this code which works fine  (I got it online from somewhere).

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
   print "<tr>"; 
   print "<th>title:</th> <td>".$info['title'] . "</td> "; 
   print "<th>info:</th> <td>".$info['information'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 print "</table>";
```

But what PHP would I use to pull just one cell?  For example, I have 9 items in my db with `productID`s how could I call just the name or price or description for that particular product?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To select distinct columns from a table, use something like: SELECT title, information FROM products - this will select columns «title» and «information» only from your products-table

Comment: You should first get some basic SQL knowledge before attempting something like this, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/selecting-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a particular row, in which, case you would just changes your query to filter for some specific value that identifies the row.  THis might look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_id = ?
```

Where `?` is the known product_id value that you want to receive the full record for.

Also, since you are just learning, I should point out that you should not learn to use `mysql_*` functions.  They are deprecated.  Learn `mysqli` or `PDO` for interacting with MySQL.

Comment: When i placed that in it didnt seem to work :/ nothing came up on my webspage

Comment: @jameslegros-massey I was just using this as an example.  You obviously need to adjust it to fit your table schema and to put in the known value for whatever field you want to use as the basis of record retrieval.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain just one cell try the following:

```
SELECT CellName FROM TableName Where productId = x
```

So to get the price you would do:

```
SELECT price FROM products WHERE productid=x
```

Where productid equals the specific product you talked about.

Comment: How do you know the cell name?

Comment: I do not know the cellname, I am just giving you a sample cellname from your question. You should be able to know the cellname, if not you can see it with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Sorry thats what i meant ( long day) how would i find out the cellname

Comment: You are fine. Well, did you create the table? You should know the name of all of your columns...

Comment: Check this out http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/070aa/3 I created a sample table for you. Play with it a little bit. You need to be able to know the names of your columns in your table, if not you can use their index using brackets [].

Answer (score 0):

if you want to understand a bit more mysql I advise you to go to PhpMyAdmin and try those and think about the result:

```
SELECT * FROM products;
SELECT title, information AS lol FROM products;
SELECT title, count(*) AS count FROM products;
SELECT * FROM products WHERE title = 'XXXX';
SELECT *, count(*), CHAR_LENGTH(title) FROM products;
SELECT title AS lol FROM products;
```

you will understand better the query language i thinks.

Comment: your example may be complicated for newbie

Answer (score 0):

please read this chapter http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/examples.html. it'll really help  you.
I  just want to say, you can retrieve any columns(s) in any condition column

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM products WHERE colmnm_name = ?
```